# Draw line within `text` attribute of a `QAction`

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have several `QAction` entries in a `QMenu`, each representing a color. Before the name of the respective color a short line in the respective color should be drawn.

For the implementation I thought about using [Qt Style Sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html), but I didn't get far. How can this be implemented?

### main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QActionGroup, QAction
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)

        colors = ("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red")

        group = QActionGroup(self.menuColor)
        for color in colors:
            text = f"<short {color} line>\t{color.capitalize()}"
            action = QAction(text, self)
            action.setCheckable(True)
            group.addAction(action)
            self.menuColor.addAction(action)
        group.setExclusive(True)
        group.triggered.connect(self.onTriggered)

    def onTriggered(self, action):
        print(action.text())


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

### mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Colors</string>
  </property>
  <property name="locale">
   <locale language="English" country="UnitedKingdom"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuMenu">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Menu</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QMenu" name="menuColor">
     <property name="title">
      <string>Color</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <addaction name="menuColor"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuMenu"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QActions cannot be uniquely stylized with stylesheets, and they only use plain text, not rich text (meaning that html tags are not supported).

The best solution is to create an icon for each action, based on the provided color:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QActionGroup, 
    QAction, QStyle)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QColor, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)

        colors = ("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red")

        group = QActionGroup(self.menuColor)
        # get the default size of a small icon, which is usually used for icons
        # in standard menu items
        size = self.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_SmallIconSize)

        for color in colors:
            # create a pixmap based on the default size
            pm = QPixmap(size, size)
            # "clear" its content (this is *very* important, otherwise the pixmap
            # will use random data based on memory dump
            pm.fill(Qt.transparent)
            # create a QPainter for the pixmap, set the pen color and draw a line
            # placed in the middle using that color
            qp = QPainter(pm)
            qp.setPen(QColor(color))
            qp.drawLine(0, size / 2, size, size / 2)
            # end painting on the pixmap, this is important also!
            qp.end()
            # create the action with an icon based on the pixmap
            action = QAction(QIcon(pm), color, self)
            action.setCheckable(True)
            group.addAction(action)
            self.menuColor.addAction(action)
        group.setExclusive(True)
        group.triggered.connect(self.onTriggered)
```

And this is the result:

[image: menu with colored icons]

Note that [`QColor(str)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#QColor-5) uses the [SVG color name specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords), like [`setNamedColor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#setNamedColor) does; this is important, as some colors don't match [Qt Global Colors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#GlobalColor-enum): for example, Qt green (`QtCore.Qt.green`) is `rgb(0, 255, 0)` (which is `lime` for SVG), while SVG green is `rgb(0, 128, 0)` (which is Qt's `QtCore.Qt.darkGreen`).